# Springboot3.0 Saml2 integrated with Microsoft Azure SAML SSO - issue when logout

Tags: spring-boot, azure, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

My code is from this tutorial https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/08/05/spring-boot-saml

My Code: https://github.com/thangdc1910/springboot-saml

i can integrate with Okta with no issue, but when i try with Azure Saml - i get below issue when logout, Please help me if you have any idea

i need to turn on **TRACE** logging to see the error

When i click logout -> i see the log below:

1. System try to **Invalidate session 9E4406398A7241878FCA60FC5E09FD51**
2. Call Get **/logout/saml2/slo/azure?SAMLResponse=XXXXX**
3. Access Denied ( If i change Websecurity setting to allow /logout/saml2... -> i get 404 error)

**strong text**

```
2023-11-17T16:06:31.268+07:00 DEBUG 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [**GET /logout/saml2/slo/azure**?SAMLResponse=fZFPa8MwDMW%2fSvDdseP8N0lgrJdCd2lLD7sMx1bWQGqHyKFjn35pSg%2bF0Zsk9KTf41WoLsMod%2b7bzX4PODqLEGw3NflKVNKZTmhaJCqmSStaWnRa084Uedt1aZGnhgQnmLB3tiYi5CTYIs6wteiV9cuIi5hGEY3yIy8lz6TIwihNPkmwAfS9VX5Vnr0fUTI2OK2Gs0O%2fVDccdmMTDAfH1O88wXLePhCPria7fRm3XZGrjEY8BZpAGdM2j0saQWmMyAByU5Dg5zJYlKvRmsyTlU5hj9KqC6D0Wh7ePnZywZfj5LzTbiBNtRqZ7tLXIoUI080IaR5G0GN47a1xVwwteNbxNIq10TTPTEoTLRJa8IWVZ1zFIgIjoGQVu%2f9sqnskB6%2f8jM%2fduzMQnNQww2smXLflYdYaEAlrKvZ8lP0Xe%2fMH&RelayState=8bdc7b83-2a89-4171-ad79-7be92224865e&Signature=eKK2erHc9N6knTUhj4fQfc7LQa8CjLvu9v6c37qZYlQ7f2lg3Djm4KiWAV0nlCKBNnLgMm%2b%2bYwe6DzRxJvTT%2biJIboeUQBMrqa8gADDpcNHgRreynTkmLnteKDHBfRLpAdM6ZLuTLPl2u9M03CU6vl7swuushNAer1rI65%2fvlcTwD6tntqc90ikU46DU5CG58NK8Mb8DK31Ypnd1R7fROWXOb7xze8ssMXFAJrem%2bEx0%2b6Ul93CBV7UEGS0Yll9UvV7qzXFtiDxmtt8VIh9IRJ7jg%2b8tTNJI5nZqsdIsr%2brnBPbS4soi4WBBn%2bA2YSF5%2fCiJTzRL%2fUmndy569L40iw%3d%3d&SigAlg=http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2f04%2fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Referer: https://login.live.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: JSESSIONID=39D5C4DB3C2CA69573B6FBFB2EAD7918

]
2023-11-17T16:06:31.268+07:00 DEBUG 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.a.t.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor   : Cookies: Parsing b[]: JSESSIONID=39D5C4DB3C2CA69573B6FBFB2EAD7918
2023-11-17T16:06:31.269+07:00 DEBUG 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter     :  Requested cookie session id is 39D5C4DB3C2CA69573B6FBFB2EAD7918
2023-11-17T16:06:31.269+07:00 DEBUG 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve   : Incoming request /logout/saml2/slo/azure with originalRemoteAddr [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1], originalRemoteHost=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1], originalSecure=[true], originalScheme=[https], originalServerName=[localhost], originalServerPort=[443] will be seen as newRemoteAddr=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1], newRemoteHost=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1], newSecure=[true], newScheme=[https], newServerName=[localhost], newServerPort=[443]
2023-11-17T16:06:31.269+07:00 DEBUG 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : **Security checking request GET /logout/saml2/slo/azure**
2023-11-17T16:06:31.269+07:00 DEBUG 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2023-11-17T16:06:31.269+07:00 DEBUG 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Not subject to any constraint
2023-11-17T16:06:31.269+07:00 DEBUG 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   :   Returning instance
2023-11-17T16:06:31.269+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@3cbb1812
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@19d27c27, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6181bc4a, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2b1a901d, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@298263fa, org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.logout.Saml2LogoutRequestFilter@3dd2b9c1, org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.logout.Saml2LogoutResponseFilter@46524ebe, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@5db9f51f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2c2a903f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3feebf9c, org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter@4b32465, org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter@224e6e88, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@369ad7da, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@70485aa, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@280484c7, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@553ce348, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4bf8b77, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6e364f1f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@34cf0e80]] (1/1)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 DEBUG 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing **GET /logout/saml2/slo/azure?SAMLResponse**=fZFPa8MwDMW%2fSvDdseP8N0lgrJdCd2lLD7sMx1bWQGqHyKFjn35pSg%2bF0Zsk9KTf41WoLsMod%2b7bzX4PODqLEGw3NflKVNKZTmhaJCqmSStaWnRa084Uedt1aZGnhgQnmLB3tiYi5CTYIs6wteiV9cuIi5hGEY3yIy8lz6TIwihNPkmwAfS9VX5Vnr0fUTI2OK2Gs0O%2fVDccdmMTDAfH1O88wXLePhCPria7fRm3XZGrjEY8BZpAGdM2j0saQWmMyAByU5Dg5zJYlKvRmsyTlU5hj9KqC6D0Wh7ePnZywZfj5LzTbiBNtRqZ7tLXIoUI080IaR5G0GN47a1xVwwteNbxNIq10TTPTEoTLRJa8IWVZ1zFIgIjoGQVu%2f9sqnskB6%2f8jM%2fduzMQnNQww2smXLflYdYaEAlrKvZ8lP0Xe%2fMH&RelayState=8bdc7b83-2a89-4171-ad79-7be92224865e&Signature=eKK2erHc9N6knTUhj4fQfc7LQa8CjLvu9v6c37qZYlQ7f2lg3Djm4KiWAV0nlCKBNnLgMm%2b%2bYwe6DzRxJvTT%2biJIboeUQBMrqa8gADDpcNHgRreynTkmLnteKDHBfRLpAdM6ZLuTLPl2u9M03CU6vl7swuushNAer1rI65%2fvlcTwD6tntqc90ikU46DU5CG58NK8Mb8DK31Ypnd1R7fROWXOb7xze8ssMXFAJrem%2bEx0%2b6Ul93CBV7UEGS0Yll9UvV7qzXFtiDxmtt8VIh9IRJ7jg%2b8tTNJI5nZqsdIsr%2brnBPbS4soi4WBBn%2bA2YSF5%2fCiJTzRL%2fUmndy569L40iw%3d%3d&SigAlg=http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2f04%2fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking Saml2LogoutRequestFilter (5/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking Saml2LogoutResponseFilter (6/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (7/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [Ant [pattern='/login/saml2/sso/{registrationId}']]]]
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (8/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to And [Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.saml2.Saml2LogoutConfigurer$Saml2RequestMatcher@5b5be49]
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (9/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter (10/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter (11/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] .p.s.w.a.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login/saml2/sso/{registrationId}']
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter (12/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.270+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter (13/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] .w.a.u.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter : Did not render default logout page since request did not match [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]]
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (14/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (15/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (16/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (17/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (18/18)
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@327ce1f5]
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@327ce1f5] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@38613ed5
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession 39D5C4DB3C2CA69573B6FBFB2EAD7918 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=39D5C4DB3C2CA69573B6FBFB2EAD7918], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-11-17T16:06:31.271+07:00 TRACE 45112 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] **o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=39D5C4DB3C2CA69573B6FBFB2EAD7918], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied**
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
```

Comment: please help me. i am stuck for long time, i know the root cause. but not sure how to fix it